# Zend_Validate_Between strange error message

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework

I am experimenting with the *Zend_Validate_Between* class.

I set it up thusly:

```
$scoreBetweenValidator = new Zend_Validate_Between(-3, 3, true);
```

so the validator should only accept values between -3 and 3, inclusive.

On an invalid value I got a *'%value%' was not found in the haystack* error message, which I think belongs to the *Zend_Validate_InArray* class (Zend_Validate_InArray::NOT_IN_ARRAY).

My problem is that I wish to use custom error messages with the *setMessages* method, but I don't know how I could set it up for this seemingly foreign message key.

I tried this:

```
$scoreBetweenValidator->setMessages(array(
        Zend_Validate_Between::NOT_BETWEEN_STRICT => 'my custom msg',
        Zend_Validate_Between::NOT_BETWEEN => 'my other custom msg',
            //'notInArray' => "doesn't work"
            //Zend_Validate_InArray::NOT_IN_ARRAY => "also doesn't work"
    ));
```

but I got a *No message template exists for key 'notInArray'* exception.

What is the preferred solution for setting custom validation messages in Zend Framework?

**As a reply to Jason:**

A *Zend_Form_Element_Select* is inside a *Zend_Form* class attached with *addElements* method.

The form doesn't have any other elements just this one, and it doesn't have any other validators, just the Between.

The select's options are all valid by default, but when I tweak the option value (with Firebug) and set an invalid value (as a self-hacking attempt) I receive the notInArray exception.

Comment: What is the context in which you are using the validator?? Is it standalone, in a validator chain, or using either Zend_Filter_Input, or Zend_Form?? The reason I ask is because Zend_Validate_Between will never, ever use the notInArray message... That's coming from a different validator.

Comment: @wabbitseason - did you ever manage to find a way to change the error message?

Comment: @almaruf I have given up on using this framework and the PHP language a long time ago. Good luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Zend_Form_Element_Select` automatically adds an InArray validator to itself.

To set the error message for it, this should do the trick:

```
$element->getValidator('InArray')->setMessage('Your inArray error message here', Zend_Validate_InArray::NOT_IN_ARRAY);
```

If you do not want the InArray validator at all, you can disable this behavior by either calling `setRegisterInArrayValidator(false)` on the element, or by passing false to the `registerInArrayValidator` configuration key on element creation.

Comment: Unfortunately only the setRegisterInArrayValidator(false) solution works. The getValidator('InArray') doesn't return anything, and the getValidators() method only lists my own Between validator. Thank you nevertheless!

Answer (score -1):

I am a newbee so I changed messages in Zend\Validate\EmailAddress.php. Afterall its email

Comment: Don't edit the core files because they be overwritten with an update. Configure the validator instead. If configuration does not give you what you want then extend the validator with your own customised validator.