# Disable notInArray Validator Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2, validation

Is there a way to disable notInArray Validator in Zend Framework 2. All the info on the internet shows how to disable the notInArray Validator in Zend Framework 1, for example in this fashion

**If you do not want the InArray validator at all, you can disable this behavior by either calling setRegisterInArrayValidator(false) on the element, or by passing false to the registerInArrayValidator configuration key on element creation.**

One the posts in stackoverflow can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991001/zend-validate-between-strange-error-message)

Unfortunately this is not possible in Zend Framework 2. So in case if anybody has a tip how this can be disabled.

Comment: Erm, validators get only attached if you tell them to. Where exactly do you want the validator to not be attached to? Your question is simply not clear at all, please update so people can get a better understanding of your prblem

Comment: Hey Sam! I have a select with no validator at all but ZF2 keeps saying that `The input was not found in the haystack`. Why this happens?

Comment: this Not in array is default validator

Comment: And how can I change an default validator?

Answer (score 10):

Since version 2.2, Zend Framework provide the ability to **disable inArray validator** calling:

```
$element->setDisableInArrayValidator(false);
```

or passing **option** to an element:

```
'disable_inarray_validator' => false
```

Comment: Okay, but a bit different. To disable you should to `'disable_inarray_validator' => true`, since twice negation is approval.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and what i did is populate the element before validate it, for example:

```
$clientForm->get('city')->setValueOptions($options);
$clientForm->setData($post);

if ($clientForm->isValid()) {
  //
} else {
  //
}
```

This don't disable notInArray valitador but you can trick it.

Answer (score 0):

I came with the same case :
while i was populating my html select element via ajax after alot of searching found no way to do it , ending with creating my own select form element , I will provide you with my changes :

```
    /**
     * Provide default input rules for this element
     *
     * Attaches the captcha as a validator.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getInputSpecification()
    {
        $spec = array(
            'name' => $this->getName(),
            'required' => true,
            //// make sure to delete the validators array in the next line  
            'validators' => array( 
                $this->getValidator()
            )
        );

        return $spec;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this at this link and thought I would post it as I found it a great solution ....
http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/zend-framework-2-extending-zendform-to-add-select-multicheckbox-emaildate-textarea-and-radio-element/

don’t try to deactive the default validator. re-values the select options values before setData.

```
$form->get('state_id')
     ->setOptions(
           array('value_options'=> $Newstatecollection)) ;
```

Saves the mess of deactivating the function if you need it elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need validation at all, add `required => false` in InputFilter

```
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'your-elements-name',
        'required' => false,
    ));
```

worked for me..