# Zend Framework 2 Forms Array notation for drop down onchange event

Tags: forms, drop-down-menu, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Framework 2 Forms using array notion for a select (drop down box). Code snippet from MenuForm.php is below:

```
 $options_for_select = $menuTable->GetParents();
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'name' => 'parent',
        'attributes' => array(
            'options' => $options_for_select,
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Select parent item',
            ),
        )
    );
```

When this drop down changes I would like to populate another drop down list on the form with a list of options that are related to the item selected in the parent drop down list.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need JavaScript to achieve such a thing. You'd make an ajax call to a data-provider-action like `GET url.dev/data/list?parent=$selectedId` which then would return a JSON-Response with the Data for List2

Comment: I am tring to achive similar results as posted in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181799/zf2-select-element-usage. 

How do I set the options available to my 2nd Drop down list based on the selection if the first. 

I would appreciate an example or a link to an example.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Zend Framework. You want to use JavaScript to listen to onchange event on the drop down, Zend Framework / PHP has no idea when it changes without refreshing the page.

Comment: To achive this i did the following:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310031/execution-of-mysql-query-in-jquery-post-method/16321890#16321890