# Execution of mySQL query in jQuery.Post method

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I have created a javascript file that contains js to trigger an event onchange of a drop down list. The JS is below:

```
// /public/js/custom.js

jQuery(function($) {
    $("#parent").change(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var parentID = $('#parent').val();
        var id = $('#id').val();
        $.post("/menu/GetMenuChildren", {pID: parentID, thisID: id }, 
            function(data){
                if(data.response === true){        
                    var $el = $("#Position");
                    $el.empty(); // remove old options
                    $.each(data.newOptions, function(key, value) {
                      $el.append($("<option></option>")
                         .attr("value", value).text(key));
                    });
                } else {
                    // print error message
                    alert("something went wrong in Post");
                }
            }, 'json');

        alert("After Post");
    });
});
```

In my Controller.php I have an function GetMenuChildrenAction as shown below:

```
public function GetMenuChildrenAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    if ($request->isPost()) 
        {
        $post_data = $request->getPost();
        $parent_id = $post_data['pID'];
        $id = $post_data['thisID'];
        //$this->form->get('Position')->SetOptionValues(
        $newOptions = $this->getMenuTable()->GetPositionsByID($parent_id, $id);
        if(isset($newOptions))
        {
            $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode(array('response' => true, 'newOptions'      => $newOptions)));
        }
        else
        {
            $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode(array('response' => false)));
        }
    }
    return $response;
}
```

In the MenuTable.php there is a Method GetPositionsByID as shown below:

```
public function GetPositionsByID($parentID, $id)
{
    if($parentID == 0)
    {
        $menu = $this->getMenu($this->id);
        $parentID = $menu->parent_id;
    }
    if(isset($parentID))
    {
        $sql = "Select ID,Label from Menu Where parent_ID = " . $parentID . " and id > 1 and id <> " . $id . " Order by Position,Label";

        try
        {
           $statement =  $this->adapter->query($sql);
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            console.log('Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n");
        }

        $res = $statement->execute();

        $rows = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($res as $row) {
            $i = $i + 1;
            $rows[$i] = array (
                $i => $row['Label']
            );
        }

        return $rows;
    }
    return array();
}
```

It all seems to be hooked up correctly, when I debug the code, I get the this line:

```
$statement =  $this->adapter->query($sql);
```

and then nothing happens. If I replace all the code in the GetPositionsByID method, and simply return an array like the following:

```
return array('1' => 'one', '2' => 'two');
```

it works great, however i want to get the data from the DB. Does anyone know why the execute would fail on this line?

```
$statement =  $this->adapter->query($sql);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: First: Why are you using `console.log()` inside a PHP context? That must be a typo, because I'd bet that produces an syntax error (no $ in front of the variable name).
Second: Have you tried running the SQL on it's own against your database to see if you are actually selecting something? It could very well be that the query is returning no rows.

Comment: The query does work, i did try the query and it does return results. I added the try catch block to see if there was an exception. There is no exception being thrown, after i step over the $statement = $this->adapter->query($sql); line, it does not go to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the adapter was null.

Comment: The lesson to learn here is to turn on all errors whilst in development. Edit your php.ini and find the line for `error_reporting` and set it to `E_ALL | E_STRICT`. Then make sure `display_errors` is on.